# Vue development version works but production doesn't (Vue CLI + Django)

Tags: django, vue.js, vuejs2

I have build a site using Django and Vue+Vuetify, with Django running the backend and Vue the front end. I have been using Vue CLI to compile by .vue files. However, now that I am preparing to move the code to production version, I have run into following issue:

Vue app created by `vue-cli-service build` does not work. When run in development mode with `vue-cli-service build --mode development` it all works fine, but the build version doesn't work. The JavaScript console doesn't give any errors. Almost nothing renders and what little renders doesn't seem to have styling included. However, I can see that axios calls do work, and using inspector shows that various elements are added to the body, they simply do not render.

However, looking at my package.json I can't see any obvious errors.

```
--package.json--
{
  "name": "vueapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "build-dev": "vue-cli-service build --mode development",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "^5.9.55",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^6.1.0",
    "sass": "~1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.4.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

And my vue.config.js

```
--vue.config.js--
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    // Should be STATIC_URL + path/to/build
    publicPath: '/static/app/',

    // Output to a directory in STATICFILES_DIRS
    outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static/app/'),

    // Django will hash file names, not webpack
    filenameHashing: false,

    // See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only
    runtimeCompiler: true,

    devServer: {
        writeToDisk: true, // Write files to disk in dev mode, so Django can serve the assets
    },

    transpileDependencies: [
      'vuetify'
    ],
    configureWebpack: {  
      resolve: {   
        alias: {  
          '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
          '@shared': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/shared')
        },
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json']
      }
    }
};
```

UPDATE 1 - 2.9.2021

`npm run build` gives on only warnings about size, not errors. Here is full output:

```
 WARNING  Compiled with 3 warnings                                                                               8.26.39

 warning

asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets:
  fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff (454 KiB)
  fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.woff2 (318 KiB)
  fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.ttf (1000 KiB)
  fonts/materialdesignicons-webfont.eot (1000 KiB)
  css/chunk-vendors.css (782 KiB)
  js/chunk-vendors.js (550 KiB)

 warning

entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  app (1.44 MiB)
      css/chunk-vendors.css
      js/chunk-vendors.js
      css/app.css
      js/app.js


 warning

webpack performance recommendations:
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

  File                                   Size                                  Gzipped

  ..\static\app\js\chunk-vendors.js      550.43 KiB                            168.66 KiB
  ..\static\app\js\app.js                142.10 KiB                            28.11 KiB
  ..\static\app\css\chunk-vendors.css    782.11 KiB                            111.41 KiB
  ..\static\app\css\app.css              0.27 KiB                              0.17 KiB

  Images and other types of assets omitted.

 DONE  Build complete. The ..\static\app directory is ready to be deployed.
 INFO  Check out deployment instructions at https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html
```

UPDATE 2 - 2.9.2021

I have discovered based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66279392/vuetify-css-missing-when-i-build-for-production) answer that adding

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

To the page fixes initial issues. It would appear that, for whatever reason, the css and scss doesn't get compiled for production. For some reason all the icons are also not included

Comment: So `npm run build` don't give any errors? Can you add the build Information to your question?

Comment: @StevenSiebert Added output from npm build. It's just warnings, not errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `publicPath: '/static/app/'` to `publicPath: ''` (vue.config.js). Sometimes the public path does not work as you expected

Comment: Tried this, didn't change anything.

Comment: and remove this as well `outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static/app/'),`

Comment: Well, that just broke it even more. I did both (set publickPath to '' and removed entire line about outputDir). Had to manually move the compiled version to proper location for django to call it, and it lost even more of the styles.

Comment: :( too bad, do you mind share the github source of this?

Comment: Not possible due to contract reasons. But like I said, weird part is that everything works fine for development, but moment I build it for production it just... collapses

Comment: I had a similar issue before but it was resolved when I handled the public path. How do you run the built codes then? Do you use Django to serve it? Try https://github.com/vercel/serve#readme  to serve the built code, if it works then maybe the problem is not due to Vue.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered a fix to the problem, altough the cause of the problem is not clear.

Like I said in the question, the CSS files get included when the app is compiled in the development mode. After discussing with a friend, we placed CSS file calls manually into the head like so:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'app/css/chunk-vendors.css' %}" >
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'app/css/app.css' %}" >
</head>
```

Why this works? We have no idea, but it does fix the app.